# Code exported in the Description column of Product Export instead of actual descriptions

Tags: export

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
```

I have exported products from Magento 2.4.5-p1. When I open the CSV file and look at the Description column, some rows show the actual Product Description while many others show the following:

```
<div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element
```

**Why is that and how to fix?**

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that along with the description, the page builder html gets into the attribute value.

I think you have some kind of customization.

What needs to be done:
Before preparing data for export, apply the strip_tags() function to the description.

Comment: How do I do that please? Can I run something in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: As I said earlier, it is necessary to prepare the data before they get into the data export, it is best to do this in the method that is responsible for preparing the data

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand any of that. I'm clicking on System -) Data transfer -) Export -) Entity type = Products. I am exporting the product list so that I can import it on another Magento 2 instance. Surely, you're not suggesting I would go through 2000+ products manually and remove the HTML formatting from each product's description? What is the story here? Are HTML tags not allowed in Description on Magento 2? I don't have any customizations.

Comment: Write a simple php script to read the csv and clean up the description text.

Comment: @Allysin, contact your programmer with this problem, he will quickly fix it

Comment: @Eugene Kapelko - I don't have a programmer. I managed to do everything myself up till now...

Comment: @paj Would I be able to find this php script on the Internet somewhere?